# Override route module from gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have this module in the routes.rb of a Rails Gem:

```
module StaticPage
  def self.remove_spree_mount_point(path)
    regex = Regexp.new '\A' + Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.spree_path
    path.sub( regex, '').split('?')[0]
  end
end
```

I need to modify it but I don't want to edit the Gem directly, instead I want to override it in my application and modify it there. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the following in config/initializers :

```
StaticPage.module_eval do
 def self.remove_spree_mount_point(path)
   # overwrite...
 end
end
```

Comment: doesn't work, it says:
    uninitialized constant StaticPage (NameError)
    (..)

Comment: Is that module inner in any other Module?

Comment: It doesn't seems so but could be. the module is defined inside the routes.rb file of a Spree extension named spree_static_content. Is there a way to know if it is inside any other module?

Comment: Could be that the module is not initialized because the extensions are loaded by the Spree module after the initialization?